Which server can be used for the headless vue storefront magento 2 site
my question is about knowing the server front with vue storefront and the backend is on Magento 2. Can anyone suggest the best and most reliable hosting server?

Yes, we are using sonassi for this, having frontend on vuestorefront & magento2 as backend.
WE are using sonnasi for almost more then 5 to 6 years and its working nicely for us.

Are they allowed to generate auto-build from GIT?
As you know that vuestorefront building by Repository Integration, Automatic Builds and Deployments, Configuration and Scaling.
